# How to refactor the combinations generator in R?

Tags: r, refactoring, combinations

I would require all the different possible combinations of the numbers from 1 to 79 with maximum 15 at a time. I have the following piece of code.

```
dets <- 1:79
all.subsets <- dets
for (i in 2:15) {
      all.subsets <- c(all.subsets, combn(x=dets, m=i, simplify=FALSE))
}
```

The code is not working after 5 iterations(`i=6`). ​I assume that the issue is due to the size of the list all.subsets. It is not able to store the new combinations being generated in the iteration `i=7` to the previous list having approximately 2 gigs. How to improve the code to overcome this issue?

Edit:

This seems to be working and the output needs to be restructured but the size of the variable still is an issue, needs to be looked upon.

```
all.subsets <- lapply(1:15, combn, x = dets, simplify = FALSE)
lengths(all.subsets)
```

Would like to hear the other better approaches.

Comment: If I understand correctly what you want, you are going to have `sum(choose(79,1:15))` elements in your list, that is 6.961719e+15. Do you have any idea of the size (in GB) of such a list?

Comment: Yes, You understood it correctly. I'm not sure of the size but I guess its very huge, I require it for my task ! So, finding the best possible way to achieve this.

Comment: Running the code for i=1:4 creates an object of 1584740 elements for a 100Mb size. That would mean something like 400 millions GB for the  6.961719e+15 total elements. I honestly don't understand how you could have made it worked in your edit

Comment: I tried in the same way for i=1:4 resulted in an object of 1584740 elements for a 96.7 Mb size. I didn't try for i=1:15 and suggested another way of doing the work instead of for loop. But the size issue still remains though ! Let me rephrase my statement to clear the ambiguity.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. If you wanted a maximum of 5 at a time, why you iterate up to m = 15?.
Moreover, are you sure you need an **explicit** representation of all the combinations? Depending on your needs, there might be a more efficient representation. How exactly are you going to use this list?

Comment: Sorry, its a typo ! These combinations are required for analysis in statistical models.